# How to sort records according to values provided in "IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-in

I want to fetch records from a table using the sequence provided in "IN" operator

```
select * from table where id in (10, 5, 30)
```

I want this result

```
ID | Name
10 | Xyz
5  | Abc
30 | Jkl
```

but it is actually showing this result

```
ID | Name
5  | Abc
10 | Xyz
30 | Jkl
```

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: it is showing first id 5 then 10 and then 30

Comment: SQL Tables are, by definition, unordered sets; if you require a specific ordering of rows you have to specify using an `order by` criteria in your query - the `in()` clause does not imply any ordering.

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon. that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` cannot be used to determine the order of results. You need to use [some kind of row value constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html):

```
select *
from (
    select 10 as id, 1 as sort union all
    select 5,        2         union all
    select 30,       3
) as custom_list
join your_table on custom_list.id = your_table.id
order by custom_list.sort
```